# Azure - Obtaining token from B2C tenant and passing it to regular tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, azure-ad-b2c

I have registered my application in Azure B2C tenant and about to consume the retrieved token in another tenant which multi. Is there any possibility on having such configuration as i am having trouble on accessing the application deployed in multi tenant by passing the token retrieved from B2C tenant.

Comment: This is something I've been wanting to do as well:)

Comment: Have you done anything towards this so far? any try

Comment: What did you **consume the retrieved token in another tenant which multi**? Based on my understanding, the token should be verified by the corresponding resource. Did you mean the resource will receive the tokens from different Azure AD B2C tenant?

Comment: @FeiXue That would be how I understood the question. The token you receive from the first tenant can be used as the authorization token when one app tries to access another, but that app must be registered with the same tenant.nYou could, I suppose, register the app with multiple tenants and then check all tenants to see if the token is valid. But I think the point of this question is to configure a tenant to automatically accept and validate tokens from other tenants without the need for custom authentication nor multiple tenant registrations for an app.

Comment: @Pytry You guys are right, i would like to gather token from one B2C tenant where my application has been registered and to consume and validate the token as well as the claim in the application deployed in another tenant which is multi. Can we have use of custom policies in this scenario? Just my doubt... Can i use of the link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrochon/2017/07/27/developing-an-azure-ad-b2c-multi-tenant-application/ for this?

Comment: Pytry and Prasanth V M. Thanks for the explanation.  AFAIK, the web API for the Azure AD B2C doesn't multi-tenant at present. You may submit the feedback about this scenario from [this site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c) if you have this requirements.

Comment: @Prasanth The linked article, "Developing an Azure AD B2C multi-tenant application", describes a different scenario where a single Azure AD B2C physical tenant is managing multiple end-customer logical tenants. (For a UserVoice idea that covers this scenario, see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrochon/2017/07/27/developing-an-azure-ad-b2c-multi-tenant-application/).) In your particular case, you can decide how to handle the token validation at your API application, as long as it is registered with the Azure AD B2C tenant (which doesn't require it to be a multi-tenant application).